# How to test void function in vue js using jest?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

Say I have this async method called `fetchItem()` which calls an api wait for its return value and set the form to ready.

```
async fetchItem() {
  this.meeting = await this.$MeetingApi.getMeeting(
    this.$route.params.id,
    false
  )
  this.formReady = true
  this.meeting.initAnswerBills()
}
```

How can I test this with jest async and mock function ? I read the documentation and I still have no clue how to implement the test.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation spying on the method works for me:

```
test('fetchItem is called properly',  async () => {

  let wrapper = shallowMount(YourComponent)

  const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'fetchItem')
    .mockImplementation(() => {
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith()
  })
})
```